DevPod desktop (macOS)... `fatal error retrieving container status: find dev container: docker ps: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH`
PROBLEM
Pullin’ me hair out. DevPod desktop on macOS 15.1 won’t fire up. I'm getting this error...

fatal error retrieving container status: find dev container: docker ps: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH

DETAILS
My Environment

macOS 15.1 ARM64
Docker 4.35.1 (173168). I’m having no issues with Docker for another Docker-only project. There are currently two working containers in Docker that don’t have to do with DevPod. I’ve never seen a container be created from DevPod yet.
DevPod desktop 0.5.21 for macOS Apple Silicon.
Warp terminal using zsh. which docker returns /usr/local/bin/docker and /usr/local/bin is currently in $PATH via ~/.zshrc.

Contents of .devcontainer.json (example from DevPod website)
{
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node",

  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": ["streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker"]
    }
  },
  "forwardPorts": [3000]
}

DevPod Workspace

Workspace Source: I chose "Folder" tab then selected the local folder where my .devcontainer.json file lives. There’s no other content in the folder right now.

DevPod Provider

Docker
Docker path field: I set it to docker. but I also tried /usr/local/bin/docker, which is the path returned by which docker in my Warp terminal that uses zsh.

DevPod settings

DevPod current version: 0.5.21
Add CLI to Path has red exclamation mark next to it, when hovering over it a info message says “Not installed”. When I click the button, it just grays out and hover over exclamation mark still says “Not installed”.
SSH Key for Git commit signing: Currently set to ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 but don't know if it needs to be an absolute path /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 (tried that as well).

Logs

fatal error retrieving container status: find dev container: docker ps: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH exit status 1

Output window in DevPod desktop when clicking Open in DevPod
[23:59:20] debug Workspace Folder already exists /Users/myuser/code/dovpod-test
[23:59:20] debug Workspace exists, skip downloading
[23:59:20] debug Skipping configuring daemon
[23:59:20] debug Using docker command 'docker'
[23:59:20] info find dev container: docker ps: exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
[23:59:20] info devcontainer up
[23:59:20] info github.com/loft-sh/devpod/cmd/agent/workspace.(*UpCmd).Run
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/cmd/agent/workspace/up.go:95
[23:59:20] info github.com/loft-sh/devpod/cmd/agent/workspace.NewUpCmd.func1
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/cmd/agent/workspace/up.go:51
[23:59:20] info github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:983
[23:59:20] info github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1115
[23:59:20] info github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1039
[23:59:20] info github.com/loft-sh/devpod/cmd.Execute
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/cmd/root.go:90
[23:59:20] info main.main
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/main.go:6
[23:59:20] info runtime.main
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.22.5.darwin-arm64/src/runtime/proc.go:271
[23:59:20] info runtime.goexit
[23:59:20] info /Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.22.5.darwin-arm64/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1222
[23:59:20] debug Connection to SSH Server closed
[23:59:20] debug Done creating devcontainer
[23:59:20] debug Done executing ssh server helper command
[23:59:20] fatal Process exited with status 1
run agent command
github.com/loft-sh/devpod/pkg/devcontainer/sshtunnel.ExecuteCommand.func2
        /Users/runner/work/devpod/devpod/pkg/devcontainer/sshtunnel/sshtunnel.go:129
runtime.goexit
        /Users/runner/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.22.5.darwin-arm64/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1222

